# How can I list all files in a Linux directory that holds basic commands and shells used by root and other users using a full path?

Tags: linux, shell-script, opensuse

I know I'll be using the command `ls` but I don't know what holds the basic commands and shells used by root and other users using the full path.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to get people to do your homework for you, piece by piece... You're not explaining your problems very well. Please edit your question to explain better what you're after exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I output a count of all files with “tty” in the filename in the Linux directory that holds files on system devices](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33570/how-do-i-output-a-count-of-all-files-with-tty-in-the-filename-in-the-linux-dir)

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (FHS).